# Angular Observable filtering

Tags: angular, filter, rxjs, observable

I met a problem for filtering an observable with an array.
Let me explain ...

I have:

- products$: Observable;
- filteredProducts$: Observable;
- selectedFilters = [['name of filter', idOfFilter], ['name of filter', idOfFilter]]; (empty for beginning)

Here is the structure of a product object: 
[image: Here is the structure of a product object]

And here is the structure of my filters array
[image]

I would like to set to filteredProducts the result of my filtering.
For filter, i have to check if the product's filter array contains the name of the filter and if  the products values array's contains filter id.

I've been writing this so far but i don't know how really filter my Observable...

```
export class ProductsFilterComponent extends BaseComponent implements OnInit {
    @Select(FiltersState.getAllFilters) filters$: Observable<any>;
    @Input() products$: Observable<Product[]>;
    filteredProducts$: Observable<Product[]>;

    public tempProducts$: Observable<Product[]>;
    public selectedFilters = [];

    constructor(
        private store: Store) { super(); }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.store.dispatch(new GetAllFilters());
        this.uns = this.products$.subscribe(res => console.log('products from filter component', res));
    }

    private filterProducts() {
      this.filteredProducts$ = this.products$.pipe(
          map(productsArray =>
              productsArray.filter(product => {
                  product.filters.filter(filters => filters.values.includes(5));
              }))
      );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`combineLatest`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest) to create an observable stream that is updated whenever any of the source observables emit a new value.

```
  filteredProducts$ = combineLatest(this.products$, this.filters$).pipe(
    map(([products, selectedFilters]) => {
      return products.filter(p => {
        // actual filter logic goes here
        return p.filters.some(pf => selectedFilters.some(f => pf == f));
      });
    })
  );
```

Check out this working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ymxqgn)

Comment: Thanks @BizzyBob, it could be a nice solution and i keep it in my head ^^. However, i had to filter my filters with the selectedFilters array

Answer (score 0):

You can declare your `filteredProducts$` in `ngOnInit()`:

```js
ngOnInit() {
   this.filteredProducts$ = this.products$.pipe(
      switchMap(products => {
         return this.filters$.pipe(
            startWith([]),
            map(filters => {
                return products.filter(/* apply your filter*/)
            })
         );
      })
   )
}
```

So everytime your `filters$` changes, the filter will apply.
With `startWith()` you can say the Observable `filters` emits an empty array before it begins to emit items emitted by the source Observable.

**EDIT**: Ah you use `filters$` already as a @Select. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response.
I understand why you tell my that, however i don't know how to make the filter because i've to map the selected filters where you say me to filter

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, you want to filter an array of products with an array of filters. And one product has also an array of filters, which have an array of values? The runtime would be horrible. I guess you have to overthink your workflow.

Comment: This solution will not update when `filters$` changes, it will only update whenever `products$` changes.  I think `combineLatest` would be a good fit for this scenario. This way, whenever either `products$` or `filters$` changes, `filteredProducts$` will be updated accordingly.  See my answer below.

Comment: @BizzyBob My example works for sure. It will update whenevery the behavior subject changes. See a small example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-5ziu8s

Comment: Your stackblitz is a bit different than above.  I made comments on your [stack blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-b7xmv3).  I'm not saying this won't work, it will work any time the `products$` observable gets a new value, but I think in this case he would want it to update whenever the `filters$` observable emits a new value.

Comment: No, it will also update when the `filters$` emits a new value. BehaviorSubject is a super class of Observable. Of course my stackblitz is overkill, but i want you to show it is also working with `switchMap`.

Comment: you are right :-)  I guess I was thinking switchmap would need a new value, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be a solution:

```js
this.filteredProducts$ = products$.pipe(
  map(
    productsArr => productsArr.filter(
      p => 
        p.filters.some(f => selectedFilters.some(([selectedF]) => selectedF === f.name) // Filter name
        && f.values.some(value => selectedFilters.some(([, filterId]) => filterId === value)) // Filter id
    )
  ),
)
```

Comment: Thanks but what about the 'f' in filter's second line ? f.values.some....  f is unknow

Comment: It's a `filter` object from `product.filters`. What do you mean by `unknown` ?

Comment: Cannot find name 'f'

Comment: i think f is isn't in the scoop private filterProducts() {
        this.filteredProducts$ = this.products$.pipe(
            map(
                productsArr => productsArr.filter(
                    p =>
                        p.filters.some(f => this.selectedFilters.some(([selectedF]) => selectedF === f.name)) // Filter name
                        && f.values.some(value => this.selectedFilters.some(([, filterId]) => filterId === value)) // Filter id
                )
            )
        );
        this.filteredProducts$.subscribe(res => console.log('filtered:', res));

    }

Comment: I'm sorry, there was an extra `)` on the first line. It should be fine now.

Comment: Okkk :p. I did it but when i subscribe and log filtered prodcuts, it's always empty

Comment: Ok i had a problem with an uppercase and i fixed it.
It works but only with one filter

Comment: Could you share the example? Also, it might be worth opening a discussion.

Comment: I wrote a new answer :-)